# Power calculation of this circuit

Tags: voltage, power, circuit-analysis, resistors, circuit-design

[image]

Can someone tell me how to approach this question. I am not sure on how to calculate it. I tried to simulate it. But got this

[image]

How to understand this and calculate the power in the circuit?

Comment: R appears to be negative.

Comment: Can R be negative in this case? If R is negative, R must be sourcing the current right? Which is not possible?

Comment: Very rare to see the current direction indicated as electron flow rather than conventional current flow.

Comment: If its electron flow, whether supply is sourcing the current or the resistor?

Comment: Not possible physically (without active elements), but the math still works out, and the direction of the arrow indicates that R is negative.

Comment: So, could you tell me whether the power is 35W or -35W?

Comment: That's a good question, is the resistor acting as a heater or a refrigerator?

Comment: I don't know how to tell that

Comment: Don't over-complicate it. Someone drew the Voltage source the wrong way around. Could happen to anyone. Just multiply 7V * 5A to get 35 W and call it a day.

Comment: I'm really confused. Newbie, are you sharing this account? Last days, you've been asking about power efficiency in switch mode power supplies, you've got hundreds of relatively involved questions, today you have an exam question about P=V•I, and have no intuition for whether a resistor heats or cools down its environments. An account here is free - if you are multiple humans, they should all be having their own accounts. It's really hard to adjust the level of answers to your knowledge if you're changing between master-thesis-level questions and first month of university.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we know that \$\text{V}=\text{I}\cdot\text{R}\$ and \$\text{P}=\text{V}\cdot\text{I}\$. So combining gives:

$$\text{P}=\text{I}^2\cdot\text{R}\tag1$$